# I will drag and drop the user into the full calendar event. I will access event id and user id

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

> `I'll drag and drop the user into the event on the calendar. I'll get the user ID and event id. User ID is now appearing, however event ID is not.`

```
 <div class="kullanicilarList-container" >
    <div class="kullanicilarList-query">
        <h3>Kullanıcı Ara</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="kullanicilarList-query">

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KullaniciAra.Arama , new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Kullanıcı Ara" })

        <button id="btnReport" name="btnReport" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sorgula</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
 var draggableUsers = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-User');
        draggableUsers.forEach(function (item) {
            item.draggable = true;
            item.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
                event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', item.dataset.itemId);
            });
        });


        calendarEl.addEventListener('dragover', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        calendarEl.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var userId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
            var eventId = event.target.getAttribute('id'); // Hedef etkinliğin kimliği
            console.log('Etkinlik Kimliği: ' + eventId);
            console.log('Kullanıcı Kimliği: ' + userId);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

for me adding eventDidMount to calendara solved it

```
eventDidMount: function (arg) {
    // Etkinliğin DOM öğesine erişin ve ID ekleyin
    var eventElement = arg.el;
    eventElement.setAttribute('id', arg.event.id);
},


 calendarEl.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var userId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
     var eventElement = event.target.closest('.fc-event'); // Etkinlik öğesini içeren konteyneri bulun
   
    
     if (eventElement) {
         var eventId = eventElement.getAttribute('id'); // Etkinlik kimliğini alın
         console.log('Etkinlik Kimliği: ' + eventId);
         console.log('Kullanıcı Kimliği: ' + userId);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="kullanicilarList-container" id='external-events'>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Kullanicilar)
    {
        <div class="draggable-User" id="draggable-@item.Id" data-item-id="@item.Id" draggable="true" style="background-color:@(item.color)">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @item.Id
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @item.FirstName
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @item.LastName
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You already answered the question once. Why do you have another answer with different code in it? Did you mean to edit your original answer? Underneath each post is a small "Edit" button. Click that to make changes. Adding it as two different answers is confusing for those trying to read your post. Take the [tour] if you are not sure how Stackoverflow's question and answer format works - it's not like a traditional forum.  Thanks.